# What is wrong with this tcpdump command?

Tags: unix, tcp, tcpdump

**I want to:**

- Intercept TCP traffic
- Only on port 80
- Only outgoing traffic
- Originating from 192.168.0.101
- Save it to verbose.txt

I have this line, but it says 'tcpdump: syntax error':

```
sudo tcpdump -A -ien0 -s0 -w verbose.txt src 192.168.0.101 port 80 and tcp
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Steffen mentioned you're missing the conjunction "and".

To address each of your requirements you would use the following filter:

```
"src 192.168.0.101 and tcp dst port 80"
```

So fully,

```
tcpdump -A -ien0 -s0 -w verbose.txt "src 192.168.0.101 and tcp dst port 80"
```

Answer (score 0):

src 192.168.0.101 **and** port 80 and tcp